# Get an array in a php file from http request

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm learning php and I'm trying to get a php file from a http request using Guzzle and then just take a particular array from those contents and ignore the rest. But I'm unsure how to get that array.

```
<?php 
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client();
$response = $client->request('GET', 'http://api-address/file.php');

$body = $response->getBody();
$decoded = json_decode($body, true);

$contents = file_get_contents($decoded);
```

When I print $contents it looks as expected, for example:

```
<?php

$var = "example string";

$array = [
   [
      'name' => 'stuff I need'
   ]
];
```

I want to just get the array, iterate through it and write each to a file but I don't know how to get just that and ignore the other stuff that isn't in that array it if that makes sense. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using ...

```
json_decode($body, true);
```

That method converts the content to array, that means that probably if you do a ...

```
var_dump($decoded);
```

you can see an array that it contents arrays inside ...

Well, I mean, you can get ...

```
$array = [
 [
 'name' => 'stuff I need'
 ]
];
```

Navigating into $json_decode() array.

If you are asking the how, well, just use the next step ...

```
$contentArray = $decoded[1] //With this you can get the array that you need.
```